# hyphenation in partly emphasised words

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, emphasis

I frequently get to typeset texts where -- due to a specific philological convention -- *shorter parts* of the words are emphasised. As far as I understand the mechanism the start/end of the `\emph`-tags are considered word-boundaries, resulting in *some* correctly hyphenated words but far too few.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage[english]{babel}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

\parbox{.7cm}{
some hyphenati\emph{o}n
}
\hspace{2cm}\parbox{.7cm}{
some hyphenat\emph{i}on
}
\hspace{2cm}\parbox{.7cm}{
some h\emph{y}phenation
}
\hspace{2cm}\parbox{.7cm}{
some h\emph{y}phe\emph{n}ation
}

\end{document}
```

I am looking for a way to have LaTeX ignore the emphasis and consider the words as wholes when determining the hyphenations.

Comment: With LuaLaTeX the restriction that a word part is considered for hyphenation only if it uses one font is lifted off. However explicit kerns (the italic correction) will again make the word not hyphenatable. So you're doomed: no italic correction means possible hyphenation but bad typesetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `\textit{...}` and `\emph{...}` insert italic corrections (a type of "implicit kern", in TeX jargon, which impedes hyphenation), `{\itshape ...}` does not. Hence, `\itshape` does not, *per se*, impede hyphenation.

If you can use LuaLaTeX and are willing to use `\itshape` to provide emphasis (and, in the process, accept a lack of italic correction of the in-word emphasized material), you can get these words hyphenated after all.

An MWE -- observe that all permissible hyphenation points are "found" in each instance:

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{showhyphens} % a LuaLaTeX-only package

\hyphenation{hy-phen-a-tion} % indicate all 3 permissible hyphenation points

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\textwidth{0.1mm}

\begin{document}
\obeylines
hyphenati{\itshape o}n
hyphenat{\itshape i}on
h{\itshape y}phenation
h{\itshape y}phe{\itshape n}ation
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is obviously a correct answer to the problem though it leads to another... That being said the automatically calculated italics correction seems to be a weak point of XeLaTeX anyway: in my font at least pairs like "f*y*" actually look *better* when written as `f{\itshape y}` while `f\emph{y}` is being spaced way too much. So LuaLaTeX and `\itshape` used for the unproblematic pairs might be the best way for me.